# Fortran Asking for Extra Parenthesis in Expression

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile a Fortran program and I get an error message I don't understand.

The error comes from this if statement:

```
        if (sw .eq. 14) then ! rho omega S=1 L=1
          amp = (-64.d0*((-1.d0 + E**(2.d0*I*phy))*x1 - I*(1.d0 + E**(2.d0*I*phy))*x2)*y*Sin(thy))/(3.d0*Sqrt(3.d0)*alpha)
        end if
```

and it is

```
           amp = (-64.d0*((-1.d0 + E**(2*I*phy))*x1 - I*(1.d0 + E**(2.d0*I*phy))*x2)*y*Sin(thy))/(3.d0*Sqrt(3.d0)*alpha)
                                                                       1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

I really don't understand why Fortran is asking for an extra parenthesis at that location. I have many other similar if statements and none of them gives me this error.

I am using the following version of Fortran on Linux:
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My spidey senses tell me that your line extends beyond column 72 on the punched card you are using for input.  There is a myriad of Qs and As here on the topic of Fortran expressions being cut off in their prime as a result of this feature of the language.  All of which I am too idle to dig out for you - hit up your favourite search engine.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @High Performance Mark in the comment, I was writing past the 72nd character on the line and Fortran was throwing an error. All I had to do was to split the line into three using

```
        if (sw .eq. 14) then ! rho omega S=1 L=1
          amp = (-64.d0*((-1.d0 + E**(2.d0*I*phy))*x1 -
     &    I*(1.d0 + E**(2.d0*I*phy))*x2)*y*Sin(thy))/
     &    (3.d0*Sqrt(3.d0)*alpha)
```

and it fixed it.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to break up such complicated expressions into a number of simpler ones and then combine them. The code tends to be more readable, easier to debug, and often easier to optimise.